# Regexpression search for document is requires or not

Tags: javascript, regex

I have json string. In that I want to check if any document required is true and document number is not passed.

JSON

```
[{"doc_name": "Birth ceritificate", "original_doc_req": true, "duplicate_doc_req": false, "doc_num": ""}..]
```

For example above string say that original document is required and document number is blank.
so I want regular expression that should give me true.

so I want something [ regexpression ]like this

```
 { contain true + ""}
```

What I am to get only string between two curly braces

```
\{(.*?)\}
```

I can do that by looping json through javascript but I want it to be done by Reg exp

Sample json string which I am having .I have have hundred of json like this

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/BLsj6/)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it ok now?

```
/true[^}]*""/
```

You can use it like this :

```
regex.test(json) // -> true or false
```

Comment: I want for both  duplicate and original if any one is true and doc_num is "" than true

Comment: so I want something like {true with""}

Comment: @rajeshkakawat Do you mean you want duplicate to be true as well?

Comment: @rajeshkakawat It sounds a bit simpler : `json.indexOf('"original_doc_req": true, "duplicate_doc_req": true, "doc_num": ""') !== -1`.

Comment: @rajeshkakawat Sorry, I guess you mean "true whether original OR duplicate is true", right?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43977/discussion-between-rajesh-kakawat-and-wared)

Answer (score 0):

You should not use regex to check the string.

Instead, parse the string (by `JSON.parse(str)`) to an javascript array (by your case), then check the result.

Comment: yes I can do that but I have lots of json string from database,which lead to perfomance issue.

Comment: I want only check if condition exist in json string or not

Comment: @rajeshkakawat This tiny json is not so scary :D

Comment: not its only one value from my db, I have hundred of like this

Comment: @rajeshkakawat Well, I'm not sure a regex can help to improve performances in this case.